# CSS: onHover button to display multiple links

Tags: html, css

I have a button that will be used as a part of a navigation bar.

What I need is when a user hovers over the button, the buttons text becomes hidden, and three different links appear inside the button.

The initial button itself shouldn't have a link attached to it, just the three options that appear after it is hovered over.

Hopefully this makes sense; Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raw9a) which might make it clearer.

```
  <ul class="ulmenu">
  <li><a href=# class="a">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest, I'd suggest the following:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Navigation</li>
    <li><a href="#opt1">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#opt2">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#opt3">Option 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

With the following CSS:

```
/* default display for all 'li' elements:
*/
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* hides the 'li' elements that follow an 'li' element,
   hides the 'li:first-child' when the 'ul' is hovered:
*/
#nav li + li,
#nav:hover li:first-child {
    display: none;
}

/* shows the 'li' elements that follow other 'li' elements,
   when the 'ul' is hovered:
*/
#nav:hover li + li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hnPcn/).

Edited with regard to question left by Rygh2014, in comments below:

> Would this work for a vertical menu as well? I take it I would just have to switch out the inline-block?

It's absolutely possible to have a vertical menu, simply switch from `display: inline-block` to `display: list-item`:

```
#nav,
#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav li {
    display: list-item;
}

#nav li + li,
#nav:hover li:first-child {
    display: none;
}

#nav:hover li + li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hnPcn/1/).

Note that I've also set the `list-style-type` property to `none`, as with any other `display` property there is no marker (under Chrome, at least), whereas with `list-item` the glyph is there by default and, if you don't want it you have to explicitly remove it.

Comment: Would this work for a vertical menu as well?  I take it I would just have to switch out the inline-block?

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question.  I'm still having problems incorporating it into my code, but nothing some tinkering can't solve!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! Best of luck with the tinkering. =)